# Resize author photo in the manuscript

Tags: ieeetran, biography

How can I resize the author's photo in IEEEtran class? Currently, I wrote

```
\begin{IEEEbiography[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mah}}]{Mahmood}

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Mahmood}
```

When I reduce `width` and `height`, a smaller photo is inserted but the canvas size remains unchanged. I mean there is a rectangular canvas in which a photo is inserted. That canvas will be unchanged while the photo looks smaller. Therefore, there is a gap between the photo and the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change some parameters used internally by the document class. If you are submitting an article to an IEEE journal then this is not a good idea. It would be better to provide a photo of the appropriate size. Still, since you asked how to do it...

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter  % Edit the following values as appropriate
\def\@IEEEBIOphotowidth{1cm}    % width of the biography photo area 
\def\@IEEEBIOphotodepth{1cm}   % depth (height) of the biography photo area
% area cleared for photo 
\def\@IEEEBIOhangwidth{1.2cm}    % width cleared for the biography photo area
\def\@IEEEBIOhangdepth{1.2cm}    % depth cleared for the biography photo area 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}]{Mahmood}  % <--- replace rule with picture
\lipsum[1]
\end{IEEEbiography}
\end{document}
```

[image: ieee]

Comment: I think so... Since I have to intentionally modify the internal code, the journal may notice that.. Anyway, thanks